# Photoshop: version control?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-management

Is there a way to save an in-between version of a PSD before overhauling it? I know there's a "Save as," but I'd much rather mark a version and save it instead.

Is the best way really to duplicate the original PSD?

EDIT
At the moment I'm using Groups to version within the PSD.

Comment: You on Mac? There's at least [Folio](https://folioformac.com/). It is possible to save those in-between versions with a script.

Comment: No photoshop has no real version control

Comment: Thanks! I'm on Windows. Never thought Git would be used for graphical design, but it makes perfect sense. :-)

Comment: In the words of Aladdin; "Not so fast, Jafar"... Git seems like a somewhat obvious solution at first glance, but my understanding is that it isn't. Folio is one of the very few apps I know that is built for this exact purpose. Using a regular Git GUI for this purpose seems doable at first, but the lack of proper image file preview makes it pretty unusable. So much so that I would claim a regular folder structure would serve you way better. It's quite cumbersome when you have to checkout each commit and perhaps open them in PS to see what they look like unless you find a similar app for Windows

Comment: In case git doesn't do what you want, I have actually made a script that does pretty much exactly what you were asking about. You can find it here if you're interested: https://github.com/joonaspaakko/Photoshop-file-versions-script (I made some changes to it just before writing this comment)

Comment: You're right about that. Your script is nice, but it still creates a full copy of whatever I'm working on. Git should be able to compress the history, right? From my rude testing this was pretty good (1PSD, 6 versions, 177MB rather than 320MB). So I'm thinking of the following workflow: Save, check in to GIT, copy hash, quick export and name it like the hash. That way I have a preview of each version and know what commit belongs to it. It's not beautiful, but it's luckily not very common. I just hoped there was something out there for my need. :-)

Comment: I just remembered something, [github has a preview for psd files](https://help.github.com/articles/rendering-and-diffing-images/). Of course that isn't ideal for everyone.

Comment: Thanks! Read about that, too, and thought that might be useful, but it's only works for two versions. In my experience it's sometimes useful to be able to show (and argue on certain elements of) different versions, so I think I'll just go with the hash-named-version previews. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get a duplicate file of the current state to save it:

1. Go to **Menu Image** > **Duplicate**

or

2. Click the **Create New Document from Current State** icon at the bottom of the **History panel**

[image: Duplicate state]

Comment: Hi @Danielillo, thanks, but these both create a complete physical copy of the files as well. I would like to have it all in one place. I've edited my post above, to indicate what my current method is (Groups). Also checked out Snapshots, but they disappear when closing the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Abstract**](https://www.goabstract.com/) , [**Trunk**](https://jointrunk.com/), [**Sympli Versions**](https://versions.sympli.io/) (but I think it only works with Sketch, same goes for [**Kactus**](https://kactus.io/)) and [**Brand.ai**](https://brand.ai/) that only works with Sketch and Illustrator.

Also, you can "cheat" and use [**InVision**](https://www.invisionapp.com/), but it will take some time for versions to sync, specially if files are too large. However, [Brand.ai is going to be merged with InVision](https://www.invisionapp.com/inside-design/announcing-invision-design-system-manager/) so there you go...